# scheduling push notification in firebase with cron job

Tags: firebase, push-notification, cron, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building an appointment booking app, I'm using FCM to handle push notifications,
so I am wondering if there is a way to schedule push notifications
For example;

When the doctor gives an appointment time, the patient should be notified few minutes to the appointment time.
I've read about cron job but I'm not sure on how to schedule it to a dynamic time.

Answer (score 2):

You can either [run a scheduled task at a fixed interval](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) (say every minute) and then send all messages for the past/next minute, or you can use Cloud Tasks to schedule the task (which is then a HTTP Cloud Function) either yourself (as Doug explained [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a)) oras shown in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/task-functions).

This topic has been covered quite a few times before, so I recommend also checking out:

- [How to create cron jobs dynamically in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60439049/how-to-create-cron-jobs-dynamically-in-firebase)
- [How to trigger cloud function based on date stored in cloud firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64083405/how-to-trigger-cloud-function-based-on-date-stored-in-cloud-firestore)
- [How to trigger a cloud function based on a timestamp attribute of a firestore document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57153845/how-to-trigger-a-cloud-function-based-on-a-timestamp-attribute-of-a-firestore-do)
- [run some code 1 hour after a document is updated with cloud function and firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63232428/run-some-code-1-hour-after-a-document-is-updated-with-cloud-function-and-firesto)